# Find max of a date column and display that value for all rows of the group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where there are 2 date columns out of a total of 4 - valid_from_dt and valid_to_dt. Other 2 columns are itm_no and price. I need to find the max of valid_to_dt in the group of itm_no, price and a continuous series of date. This will use some extent of gaps and islands solution. Then gotta display that max value in all rows of that group. I will share the code of the table.

```
create table price_tab (itm_no varchar2(10), price number, valid_from_dt date, valid_to_dt date);

insert into price_tab values ('A001', 83, '01-JAN-21', '05-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 83, '06-JAN-21', '12-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 98, '13-JAN-21', '17-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 83, '19-JAN-21', '24-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 83, '25-JAN-21', '30-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A002', 71, '01-JAN-21', '11-JAN-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 83, '31-JAN-21', '04-FEB-21');
insert into price_tab values ('A001', 77, '17-FEB-21', '25-FEB-21');
```

As seen above there are 2 rows for itm_no A001 priced 83 from 1st Jan to 12th Jan. So the 1st row should have max_valid_to as 12th Jan. The itm_no A001 priced at 83 is also available from 19th Jan to 4th Feb. There is a gap from 13th to 18th Jan for A001 priced at 83.

I have the query to get max valid_to_dt for the group of itm_no, price and a continuous series of date :

```
select itm_no, price,  max(valid_to_dt) from (
select t.*,
       row_number() over(partition by itm_no order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt) rn1
      ,row_number() over(partition by itm_no, price order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt) rn2
from price_tab t ) x group by itm_no, price, rn1-rn2 order by 1, 3;
```

But I cant find a way to get the max valid_to_dt and display it for all rows with itm_no, price and continuous series of date. Can someone please guide me?

[image: output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your expected output.

Comment: I have an edit to my question. One extra column has been added and another data set. Its basically the same question but the table has an extra column and new scenario of data. Shall I post a new question or edit the above one?

Comment: Ok, I will go ahead and update the question. If anyone wants me to make a new post, I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to return the last `VALID_TO_DT` for each contiguous set of rows where the price is the same and to show that on all rows within that set of rows.

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT itm_no,
       price,
       valid_from_dt,
       MAX( valid_to_dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY itm_no, mno ) AS valid_to_dt
FROM   price_tab
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY itm_no
  ORDER BY valid_from_dt
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( new_price same_price* )
  DEFINE
    same_price AS PREV(price) = price
)
```

or, you can use:

```sql
SELECT itm_no,
       price,
       valid_from_dt,
       MAX(valid_to_dt) OVER ( PARTITION BY itm_no, mno ) AS valid_to_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         row_number() over(
           partition by itm_no order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt
         )
         - row_number() over(
              partition by itm_no, price order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt
         ) AS mno
  FROM   price_tab t
)
ORDER BY itm_no, valid_from_dt;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | ITM_NO | PRICE | VALID_FROM_DT | VALID_TO_DT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A001 | 83 | 01-JAN-21 | 12-JAN-21 |
> | A001 | 83 | 06-JAN-21 | 12-JAN-21 |
> | A001 | 98 | 13-JAN-21 | 17-JAN-21 |
> | A001 | 83 | 19-JAN-21 | 04-FEB-21 |
> | A001 | 83 | 31-JAN-21 | 04-FEB-21 |
> | A001 | 83 | 25-JAN-21 | 04-FEB-21 |
> | A001 | 77 | 17-FEB-21 | 25-FEB-21 |
> | A002 | 71 | 01-JAN-21 | 11-JAN-21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=900991111f20a94067b8bf78c0ab22c8)*

Comment: Yes the sample data output is exactly what you have posted. I will use that to put in my question.

Comment: That really helped. I got the desired output. Since the Oracle version is 11 the 2nd method worked like a charm. I clicked on upvote but I dont have 15 reputation points so it could not get upvoted. I wish there was some option to make your post as answer. Please do let me know if there is any, I will be more than happy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want your query with window fucntions rather than aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       max(valid_to_dt) over (partition by itm_no, price, rn1 - rn2)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over(partition by itm_no order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt) as rn1,
             row_number() over(partition by itm_no, price order by valid_from_dt, valid_to_dt) as rn2
      from price_tab t
     ) t ;
```